# Opening Android app using notification & getLaunchIntentForPackage doesn't go through LauncherActivity

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, launch

I am using Firebase (FCM) to show Push Notifications to the user and I am running into a weird problem.

The code I have works for the following scenarios (using FirebaseMessagingService):

- App in foreground - Receiving data in onReceive() and showing a popup inside app.
- App in background - Receiving data in onReceive() and showing a notification for the user. If this is clicked the app will be brought back to front. ***The intent from this is received in LauncherActivity followed by a finish() call which takes me to whatever activity I already had open.***
- App completely closed - same as background. App will be started and intent will be handled in LauncherActivity before calling finish() on that.

And here is where it gets interesting:

- App completely closed -> open it through notification (intent received in LauncherActivity) -> put the app in background and send another notification -> when this notification is clicked the LauncherActivity is completely ignored (onCreate is no longer called) and I get taken straight to whatever activity I already had. The intent here has no extras or categories.
  Why is LauncherActivity being bypassed in this specific case? Keep in mind that this works fine if the app was initially started normally (not by clicking on a notification)

```
Intent mainIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName()); 
if (mainIntent != null) {
    mainIntent.addCategory(NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY);
    mainIntent.putExtra(.........);
}
PendingIntent pendingMainIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id));
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingMainIntent);
//.....icon, color, pririty, autoCancel, setDefaults, setWhen, setShowWhen, contentText, setStyle

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (notificationManager != null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
            getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),
            getString(R.string.default_notification_channel),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id));
    }
    notificationManager.notify(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch an app for the first time, Android remembers the `Intent` that was used to launch it. Normally, when you launch an app from the HOME screen, this is an `Intent` that contains ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER. If your app then goes to the background (for whatever reason), and the user later taps the icon on the HOME screen, the same launch `Intent` is used. Android matches this against the `Intent` used to launch the app for the first time, and if these match, Android doesn't launch a new `Activity`, it just brings the task containing the app from the background to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it got moved to the background. Under normal circumstances, this is exactly the behaviour that you want (and that the user expects).

However, when the app is launched for the first time from a `Notification`, this can mess things up. In your case, this is what you are seeing. You launch the app from a `Notification` and Android remembers the `Intent` used (from the `Notification`), when you later launch the app (again from a `Notification`), android matches the `Intent` in the `Notification` with the `Intent` used to launch the app for the first time, and thinks you want to bring the existing app task from the background to the foreground.

There are several ways to deal with this, depending on the behaviour that you want to have. The best thing to do is probably not to launch your root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) from the `Notification`. Instead launch a different `Activity` and have that `Activity` determine what it should do next (ie: redirect to the root `Activity` or something else, depending on the state of your app). You should also set the `NO_HISTORY` and `EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flags on the `Intent` that you put in the `Notification`. This will ensure that Android won't remember this `Intent` as the one that launched the app.

Comment: I used a separate activity which I start with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS. This starts the app or brings it to front as needed. From this activity, I either finish or start the app launcher (if app was dead). If I start the app from this activity through launcher, the next time a notification is clicked, the problem is again there, this time the separate activity is bypassed completely and I get no intent data anywhere.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your latest manifest there. I'm having trouble following your comment.

Comment: Figured it out. I'll post the code as soon as I have some time. Your explanation on how the system matches the Intent was very helpful. Thank you.