# Android back to an activity in backstack or open it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I am having difficulty managing the activities in the backstack. If the user taps on the notification then activity B is opened, at some point activity B will be closed and I need to open activity A, but here I can have two cases, if activity A is already open and is in the backstack then I want to go back to this without reopening it, if instead the activity A has never been opened then I have to open it.
How can I achieve this?

```
val notifyIntent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            putExtra(MODEL_KEY, model)
        }

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(
            Date().time.toInt(),
            Builder(context, NotificationSettings.channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(NotificationSettings.smallIconId)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification?.title ?: remoteMessage.data[BODY])
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification?.body ?: remoteMessage.data[SOURCE])
                .setStyle(
                    BigTextStyle().bigText(
                        remoteMessage.notification?.body ?: remoteMessage.data[SOURCE]
                    )
                )
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(
                    getActivity(
                        context, 0, notifyIntent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    )
                )
                .setAutoCancel(true).build()
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this code in `ActivityB`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will return to a previous instance of `ActivityA` (and remove any other activities that are in the task stack that were on top of that), or if there is no existing instance of `ActivityA` in the task, then it will create a new one.

Comment: this works well but if after opening the application from the notification with activity B, having closed activity B and starting activity A, if I receive a new notification, activity B does not start.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code that you use to create the Notification to launch `ActivityB`

Comment: You could try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` in the `Intent` for the `Notification`. See my explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63901433/769265

Comment: Was this helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Why not? What did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy.

> ```
> //this functions you put true if opened from notification
> private boolean isOpenNotification;
>
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>         if (isTaskRoot() && isOpenNotification) {
>             finish();
>             //open your activity here
>         } else {
>             setResult(RESULT_OK);
>             super.onBackPressed();
>         }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that kind of behavior by following this : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#DirectEntry